# La función Ratio de Sharpe solicita que los nombres de las filas sean fechas que ya están

Tags: r

Tengo un marco de datos de stock diariamente desde el cual trato de obtener el Ratio de Sharpe

```
> head(df)
        Date  .SXQR  .SXTR  .SXNR  .SXMR  .SXAR  .SX3R  .SX6R  .SXFR  .SXOR  .SXDR
1 2000-01-03 364.94 223.93 489.04 586.38 306.56 246.81 385.36 403.82 283.78 455.39
2 2000-01-04 345.04 218.90 474.05 566.15 301.13 239.24 374.64 390.41 275.93 434.92
3 2000-01-05 338.22 215.88 464.20 542.29 298.22 239.55 373.26 383.48 272.54 430.05
4 2000-01-06 343.13 218.18 470.82 529.33 300.69 249.75 377.26 383.48 272.47 434.15
5 2000-01-07 349.46 220.10 478.87 531.65 306.50 255.17 381.19 390.23 273.76 447.02
6 2000-01-10 356.20 223.01 484.07 581.82 310.84 252.75 387.74 393.75 278.76 453.80
```

## Con SharpeRatio.annualized

También probé con una de las bibliotecas ya construidas `SharpeRatio.annualized` en df2 cuyos nombres son formatos de fecha estándar:

```
>df2 <- df
>rownames(df2) <- df2$Date
>SharpeRatio.annualized(df2, Rf = 0, scale = NA, geometric=TRUE)
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

Sin embargo, parece que no se tienen en cuenta los nombres como fecha.

## SharpeRatio a la mano

Intenté hacerlo usando el método de esta publicación de blog que calcula la función Return.excess de PerformanceAnalytics, luego calculo la proporción de Sharpe manualmente. Ya tengo las devoluciones mensuales de:

```
percent_change2 <- function(x)last(x)/first(x) - 1
monthly_return <- df %>% 
  group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr) %>% 
  as.matrix()
```

Sin embargo, cuando llegamos a la Ratio de Sharpe usando:

```
portfolio_excess_returns <- Return.excess(portfolio_monthly_returns, 
                                          Rf = .0003)
sharpe_ratio_manual <- round(
  mean(portfolio_excess_returns) / StdDev(portfolio_excess_returns), 4
)
```

Tengo el error siguiente

```
> portfolio_excess_returns <- Return.excess(monthly_return, 
+                                           Rf = .0003)
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

De hecho, ya no tengo las fechas:

```
          .SXQR        .SXTR       .SXNR        .SXMR        .SXAR       .SX3R
[1,] -0.09048063 -0.070602420 -0.05688696  0.138527917 -0.079429802 -0.07370042
[2,] -0.02547240 -0.017752597  0.08995378  0.227683167 -0.007488398  0.02070630
[3,]  0.04344800  0.072023472 -0.04419912 -0.118953102  0.042191076  0.05908376
[4,]  0.07704088 -0.001580195  0.03846154 -0.009596822 -0.030854538  0.01882887
[5,] -0.02398056 -0.058094333 -0.05729563 -0.193718178 -0.034808588  0.02313015
[6,]  0.05252934  0.007013127 -0.04359662 -0.016661155 -0.051900140  0.02085395
```

¿Cómo puedo agregarlos a la función month_returns para calcular la SharpeRatio?

#### Reproducir el error

El archivo de datos es [aquí](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MExW-r0NNGAlMxlQh_tjOscpm6xBiMsfMKRPQykJgr8/edit?usp=sharing).

Para crear df solo necesitas:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Sector-STOXX600", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
df[2:19] <- data.matrix(df[2:19])
```

Comment: Respondida aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/246437/62097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `Return.excess`esta esperando un objeto que al menos sea coercible a una serie de tiempo del tipo `xts`, y la matriz que le estas pasando es una matriz plana sin información de tiempos. Esto lo puedes verificar ahora con:

```
xtsible(monthly_return)
[1] FALSE
```

Lo que si puedes hacer es modificar un poco la generación de `monthly_return` para dejar información de las fechas y generar un objeto de la clase `xts` directamente:

```
monthly_return <- df %>% 
    group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
    ungroup()

# Generamos el xts, indicando la columna con la info de tiempo
monthly_return <- xts(monthly_return[,-1], order.by=monthly_return$gr)

xtsible(monthly_return)
[1] TRUE
```

Sino, otra forma más sencilla, es convertir `gr` en nombre de las filas, lo que hace automáticamente al df o matriz "coercible" a un `xts`

```
monthly_return <- df %>% 
    group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    column_to_rownames('gr')

xtsible(monthly_return)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me permite obtener `monthly_return` de una otra manera. Sin embargo tengo dos problemas. El primero es que cuando intento utilizarlo para el Sharpe ratio, este me devuelve NA. El segundo es que intenté utilizar la misma lógica a `yearly_returns`, devoluciones anuales y me refirió `Error in yearly_return$gr : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Una cosa que observé que la planilla que has compartido tiene varias cotizaciones NA, eso sin duda puede provocar la salida que mencionas.

Comment: Si, tienes enteramente razon. Actualmente estoy investigando este problema [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/246688/c%C3%B3mo-calcular-los-retornos-anuales-cuando-hay-valores-faltantes)