# ¿Cómo calcular los retornos anuales cuando hay valores faltantes?

Tags: r

Tengo un marco de datos de stock diariamente desde el cual trato de obtener los retornos anuales:

```
> head(df)
        Date  .SXQR  .SXTR  .SXNR  .SXMR  .SXAR  .SX3R  .SX6R  .SXFR  .SXOR  .SXDR
1 2000-01-03 364.94 223.93 489.04 586.38 306.56 246.81 385.36 403.82 283.78 455.39
2 2000-01-04 345.04 218.90 474.05 566.15 301.13 239.24 374.64 390.41 275.93 434.92
3 2000-01-05 338.22 215.88 464.20 542.29 298.22 239.55 373.26 383.48 272.54 430.05
4 2000-01-06 343.13 218.18 470.82 529.33 300.69 249.75 377.26 383.48 272.47 434.15
5 2000-01-07 349.46 220.10 478.87 531.65 306.50 255.17 381.19 390.23 273.76 447.02
6 2000-01-10 356.20 223.01 484.07 581.82 310.84 252.75 387.74 393.75 278.76 453.80
```

Estoy capaz calcularlo con:

```
percent_change2 <- function(x)last(x)/first(x) - 1 # que son last y first?
> yearly_return <- df %>% 
+     group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "year")) %>%
+     summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
+     ungroup()
```

Pero me devuelve Nas en ciertos años. En efecto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cuando intento generar el xts tengo problemas:

```
> # Generamos el xts, indicando la columna con la info de tiempo
> yearly_return <- xts(monthly_return[,-1], order.by=monthly_return$gr)
Error in xts(monthly_return[, -1], order.by = monthly_return$gr) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

#### Reproducir el error

El archivo de datos es [aquí](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MExW-r0NNGAlMxlQh_tjOscpm6xBiMsfMKRPQykJgr8/edit?usp=sharing).

Para rerproducir `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Sector-STOXX600", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
df[2:19] <- data.matrix(df[2:19])
```

## Actualización

Incluso si no tengo más problemas con los datos faltantes, todavía no puedo calcular las devoluciones anuales.

```
> # Replacing missing values
> nas <- which(apply(df[, -1], 1, FUN=function(x) any(is.na(x))))
> # Vemos de forma ordenada con los valores anteriores y posteriores
> # Solo para verificar 
> ver <- c(nas, nas - 1, nas + 1)
> ver <- ver[order(ver)]
> # Imputamos con el promedio entre el valor anterior y el posterior
> df[nas, -1] <- (df[nas-1,-1] + df[nas+1,-1])/2
> 
> yearly_return <- df %>% 
+   group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "year")) %>%
+   summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+ 
+ # Generamos el xts, indicando la columna con la info de tiempo # ISSUE : there is nas
+ yearly_return <- xts(yearly_return[,-1], order.by=yearly_return$gr)
Error in xts(yearly_return[, -1], order.by = yearly_return$gr) : 
  object 'yearly_return' not found
```

Comment: Si no puedes simplemente eliminar las filas con valores `NA`, me temo que el problema es un poco más profundo y complejo, se trata de la imputación de valores faltantes. Es decir: ¿que cotización "inventar" cuando no tenemos ninguna? Hay múltiples criterios, desde usar un valor random de las cotizaciones existentes, usar la media de la columna, la media entre los valores más próximos, una regresión y predecir el valor, etc. De hecho en R hay paquetes únicamente para esto. ¿Que valor te parece debería imputarse en las cotizaciones NA según tu criterio?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Si, tienes razón. Deciria el valor más cercano. ¿El de antes, por ejemplo? O el promedio entre antes y después.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La imputación de valores faltantes es un tema largo y profundo, no sé si se han escrito libros, pero capítulos completos sobre esto, seguro. Hay mucha paquetería para manejar especialmente este tema: `MICE`, `Amelia`, `missForest`, `Hmisc`, `mi`, `tidyimpute`, etc. Te lo comento simplemente para que dimensiones la magnitud del problema.

En principio, según lo que dices te alcanzaría con usar la media entre el valor anterior y el siguiente. Esto es relativamente sencillo de resolver. El siguiente código lo hace, pero asumiendo que por cada `NA`, tienes un valor anterior y uno posterior, que no es `NA`, lo cual pude verificar que efectivamente en tu caso es así. Si tuvieras "huecos" de `NA´s` más grandes o si el primer o último valor lo fueran,  hay que pensar una solución más compleja.

Primero obtenemos las filas dónde alguna de las columnas fuera `NA`

```
nas <- which(apply(df[, -1], 1, FUN=function(x) any(is.na(x))))
```

Podemos revisarlas:

```
# Vemos de forma ordenada con los valores anteriores y posteriores
# Solo para verificar 
ver <- c(nas, nas - 1, nas + 1)
ver <- ver[order(ver)]
df[ver,]


# A tibble: 21 x 19
   Date                .SXQR .SXTR .SXNR .SXMR .SXAR .SX3R .SX6R .SXFR .SXOR .SXDR .SX4R
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2001-01-22 00:00:00  353.  223.  421.  540.  289.  282.  400.  469.  280.  529.  424.
 2 2001-01-23 00:00:00  354.  222.   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 
 3 2001-01-24 00:00:00  354.  225.  426.  548.  287.  282.  400.  481.  282.  531.  425.
 4 2001-02-21 00:00:00  342.  226   406.  487.  310.  298.  411.  454.  283.  562.  440.
 5 2001-02-22 00:00:00  343.  227.   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 
 6 2001-02-23 00:00:00  335.  226.  399.  487.  300.  298.  403.  440.  283.  553.  432.
 7 2003-04-30 00:00:00  262.  131.  184.  193.  193.  254.  293.  242.  202.  363.  282.
 8 2003-05-01 00:00:00  261.  131.   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 
 9 2003-05-02 00:00:00  262.  132.  184.  190.  193.  246.  296.  241.  203.  371.  283.
10 2003-12-23 00:00:00  317.  174.  231.  235.  245.  264.  337.  296.  249.  401.  327.
# ... with 11 more rows, and 7 more variables: .SXRR <dbl>, .SXER <dbl>, .SXKR <dbl>,
#   .SX7R <dbl>, .SX8R <dbl>, .SXIR <dbl>, .SXPR <dbl>
```

Y ahora sí hacemos la imputación final:

```
# Imputamos con el promedio entre el valor anterior y el posterior
df[nas, -1] <- (df[nas-1,-1] + df[nas+1,-1])/2
# Resultado
df[ver,]

# A tibble: 21 x 19
   Date                .SXQR .SXTR .SXNR .SXMR .SXAR .SX3R .SX6R .SXFR .SXOR .SXDR .SX4R
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2001-01-22 00:00:00  353.  223.  421.  540.  289.  282.  400.  469.  280.  529.  424.
 2 2001-01-23 00:00:00  353.  224.  423.  544.  288.  282.  400.  475.  281.  530.  425.
 3 2001-01-24 00:00:00  354.  225.  426.  548.  287.  282.  400.  481.  282.  531.  425.
 4 2001-02-21 00:00:00  342.  226   406.  487.  310.  298.  411.  454.  283.  562.  440.
 5 2001-02-22 00:00:00  338.  226.  402.  487.  305.  298.  407.  447.  283.  558.  436.
 6 2001-02-23 00:00:00  335.  226.  399.  487.  300.  298.  403.  440.  283.  553.  432.
 7 2003-04-30 00:00:00  262.  131.  184.  193.  193.  254.  293.  242.  202.  363.  282.
 8 2003-05-01 00:00:00  262.  131.  184.  192.  193.  250.  294.  242.  202.  367.  282.
 9 2003-05-02 00:00:00  262.  132.  184.  190.  193.  246.  296.  241.  203.  371.  283.
10 2003-12-23 00:00:00  317.  174.  231.  235.  245.  264.  337.  296.  249.  401.  327.
# ... with 11 more rows, and 7 more variables: .SXRR <dbl>, .SXER <dbl>, .SXKR <dbl>,
#   .SX7R <dbl>, .SX8R <dbl>, .SXIR <dbl>, .SXPR <dbl>
```

Comment: Realmente interesante @PatricioMoracho, como experiencia profesional hubo una compañía que perdió -en un siniestro- algunos de sus registros correspondientes a sus ventas de algunas filiales, y la data quedaba como se expone en este caso: con vacíos (`NA`), en ese caso particular como bien señalas en uno de tus comentarios, se tuvo que tomar varias variables a fin de modelar el comportamiento de los históricos.

Comment: Hola @HubertRonald!, leí algo (poco) de este tema, y hay algoritmos realmente complejos para esto. Evidentemente es un tema muy delicado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio Moracho! Sin embargo, mientras que ahora tengo una dataframe completa todavía tengo el problema para calcular `yearly_return`. Pero no rstudio no me dia un mensaje de error que me ayuda a comprender porque. Actualicé la pregunta

Comment: @ThePassenger, el tema es que luego del `ungroup() %>%` sigues teniendo abierto el pipe, elimina ese pipe final, creo que debería funcionar.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Si exactamente! Lo siento, no lo sabía y hago un montón de copiar código para llegar a mi fin, pero leo todas las respuestas para comprender mejor.